# How to generate a unique deposit address for a Monero wallet

Tags: address, javascript

Hi I want to generate a unique deposit address for my Monero wallet. Please let me know if I can do this using javascript, without unlocking my wallet, just using the wallet or public key, or any other method.

Answer (score 1):

To create a subaddress, you need the wallet private keys. Assuming you have these, you can create them in javascript using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/subaddress), as an example.

You cannot do this having only the public key, you need both the private view key and public spend key.

Comment: Secret view key only.

Comment: The linked javascript module requires both spend and view keys. That is, public spend key and secret view key.

Comment: OK. Then you might want to add a comment that this requirement is only for this particular software.

Comment: The point is (which I have reworded in the answer), is you need both the public spend key and private view key. You cannot create subaddreses (using anything) without both of these.

Comment: I tried but its not giving me unique address , always same

Comment: If you pass the same parameters (e.g. the account and subaddress index parameters), you will get the same result. Pass different parameters, get different results.